# Bootstrap - Bringing content of a div in the center

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I started learning Web Designing and I have some doubt in Grid System.
Question might seem very nooby, so assume that I have no knowledge about it. 
I have the following code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Grid System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: yellow">
                <h4>Grid</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: grey">
                <h4 >System</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: yellow">
                <h4>Practice</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Suppose I wish to print "Grid" in the center of it's div. How can I do it?

Comment: http://goo.gl/xbDlnN

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to the h4: class="text-center". That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
<div class="col-md-4 text-center" style="background-color: yellow">
     <h4>Grid</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to positionate only the Grid word(*the rest part of it`s div will be on left*) you can simply use the **center** html tag:

```
<center><h4>Grid</h4></center>
```

Or if you want to move the entire content of the div to the center you can add  the `text-center` class to div tag as it was mentioned before my answer:

```
<div class="col-md-4 text-center" style="background-color: yellow">
    <h4>Grid</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use :**

```
<div class="col-md-4 text-center" style="background-color: grey">
```

**Example:** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mahajanankur/Lurqg02n/)